# Django arranging model foreign key attributes after delete()

Tags: python, django, view, models

I have a model like so:

```
class RepairOrder(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
ro_number = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(999999999999)])
service_writer = models.ForeignKey(ServiceWriter, null=True, blank=True)
RO_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'Pending'),
    ('O', 'Open'),
    ('C', 'Closed')
)
ro_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, choices=RO_STATUS_CHOICES)
open_date = models.DateTimeField()
closed_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
mileage = models.IntegerField(blank=False, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999999999999)])
line_number_1 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  related_name='line_number_1')
line_number_2 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  related_name='line_number_2')
line_number_3 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  related_name='line_number_3')
line_number_4 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
                                  , related_name='line_number_4')
line_number_5 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  related_name='line_number_5')
line_number_6 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  related_name='line_number_6')
line_number_7 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  related_name='line_number_7')
line_number_8 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  related_name='line_number_8')
line_number_9 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  related_name='line_number_9')
line_number_10 = models.ForeignKey(JobLine, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                   related_name='line_number_10')
vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, blank=False, related_name='vehicle')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.ro_number)
```

Some of these objects might have

```
line_number_(1 through 5)
```

assigned to a JobLine object and the remaining set as Null. 
Other RepairOrder objects may only have

```
line_number_(1 through 3)
```

assigned to a JobLine object while the remaining are set as Null. But during the creation of a RepairOrder object the

```
line_number_(x)
```

attributes are always assigned in ascending order starting from 1.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
Lets assume I have a RepairOrder that has

```
line_number_(1 through 5)
```

assigned to JobLine objects and the rest are assigned as a Null value. I want to be able to delete the JobLine object assigned to the

```
line_number_3
```

attribute of a RepairOrder object and have the remaining filled attributes re arranged to fill the

```
line_number_(1-4)
```

attributes of that RepairOrder object.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
views.py
def advanced_delete_line(request, pk, jl):
user = request.user

if request.method == "POST":
    raise PermissionDenied
else:
    # Get RepairOrder object with pk passed in from url
    ro_obj = RepairOrder.objects.get(pk=pk, user=user)  
    # Get attribute object of 'line_number_(jl passed in from url)
    ro_line = getattr(ro_obj, "line_number_" + str(jl))  
    # Delete this object
    ro_line.delete()
    # Get the object assigned to the next numerically higher attribute or RepairOrder object
    x = int(jl) + 1
    for i in range(10-int(jl)):  # Only loop as many times is needed
        # Get the object assigned to the next numerically higher attribute or RepairOrder object
        line = getattr(ro_obj, "line_number_" + str(x))
        y = x - 1
        # Assign the previously retrieved object to the next lower job_line_attribute
        line_2 = setattr(ro_obj, "line_number_" + str(y), line)
        if line is None:
            pass
        else:
            line_2.save()
        # Do it all over again but starting at the next numerically higher attribute
        x += 1

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/advanced/repair-order/' + str(pk) + "/")
```

I am having little to no luck with this method. Can anyone provide me with a better way to do this?

Comment: This seems like the wrong structure. You need a many-to-many relationship; to do the ordering you can have a chain through model with an order field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save line_2 after setting it to None the first time.  See if this change in the for-loop helps:

```
for i in range(10-int(jl)):  # Only loop as many times is needed
    # Get the object assigned to the next numerically higher attribute or RepairOrder object
    line = getattr(ro_obj, "line_number_" + str(x))
    y = x - 1
    # Assign the previously retrieved object to the next lower job_line_attribute
    line_2 = setattr(ro_obj, "line_number_" + str(y), line)
    line_2.save()
    if line is None:
        break
    else:
        # Do it all over again but starting at the next numerically higher attribute
        x += 1

return HttpResponseRedirect('/advanced/repair-order/' + str(pk) + "/")
```

Comment: Still doesn't do the trick. Im curious if my method just isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out some issues with my logic. I was assigning the setattr() function to a variable when it doesn't work like that. You need to use the settattr() function like so:

```
replacement_value = "value"
setattr(object, "attribute_name", replacement_value)
object.save()
```